# Reading URLs from a HTML webpage and writing them to a file

Tags: java, url, arraylist, html

I want to create a simple program that only reads the URLs contained within `<a>` tags in the source code of a webpage specified by the user. As I am new to Java, any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far, but this only adds the entire webpage to the file...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class siteReader {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL address = new URL(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a webpage address:"));  
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(address.openStream()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Try looking at the project [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) it should be able to do exactly what you want in a few lines of code.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to Jsoup?

Comment: Yes, there are many alternatives to jsoup. Google "parsing html with java". jsoup just is one very easy method that requires little work by you.

Answer (score 2):

[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) would do what you want with something like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(address).get();
Elements links = doc.select("a");
```